# Error when updating in terminal

Tags: command-line, updates

```
rinka@rinka-pc:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for rinka: 
Get:1 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease [2,852 B]
Err:1 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                     
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F24AEA9FB05498B7
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal InRelease [17.5 kB]
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:5 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal InRelease     
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 531EE72F4C9D234C
Hit:6 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease
Hit:7 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F24AEA9FB05498B7
E: The repository 'https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 531EE72F4C9D234C
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
rinka@rinka-pc:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

from steam repo [docs](http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/):

Download [steam.gpg](http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/stable/steam.gpg) and copy it to `/usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg`, example:

```shell
sudo mv -v ~/Downloads/steam.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-add expired GPG keys. Open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys F24AEA9FB05498B7 531EE72F4C9D234C
```

and then update package lists with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't edit answers yet, I'm just making a new answer.

As N0rbert said, expired GPG keys have to be re-added. This can be done by executing:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F24AEA9FB05498B7 531EE72F4C9D234C
```

This should normally fix the problem. However, there is another problem, because this will add Steam's GPG key to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg`, even though Steam's sources file (`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam-stable.list`) specifies to look for `/usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg`<sup>[source](https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/)</sup>. This can be fixed by executing:

```
sudo apt-key export B05498B7 | sudo gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg
```

I was having the same problem, and this seemed to fix it.