# Error when using the sudo apt-get update command

Tags: apt, gnupg

List of PPAs:

[image]

Error output from terminal:

```
nessie27@nessie27-MS-7A38:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for nessie27:
Exist:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Gender:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Exist:3 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Exist:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Exist:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Exist:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x nodistro InRelease
Exist:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Gender:8 https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/symfony/stable/deb/ubuntu jammy InRelease [5121 B]
Exist:9 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy pgadmin4 InRelease
Exist:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Gender:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease [8041 B]
Exist:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/damentz/liquorix/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Exist:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/daniel-milde/gdu/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Oshb:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease
   The following signatures cannot be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Exist:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Exist:15 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Exist:16 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Exist:17 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Exist:18 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease
Exist:19 https://deb.tableplus.com/debian/22 tableplus InRelease
Error: 18 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease
   The following signatures cannot be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F24AEA9FB05498B7
Exist:20 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:21 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 InRelease
Exist:22 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 Release
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG Error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures cannot be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: Repository "https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease" is not signed.
N: Updating from this repository cannot be done securely, so it is disabled by default.
N: For information on creating a repository and user settings, see the apt-secure(8) man page.
W: An error occurred while verifying the signature. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG Error: https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease: The following signatures cannot be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F24AEA9FB05498B7
```

Comment: It looks like you followed some old instructions when adding Wine (and possibly Steam) - at least the keys aren't working. Please only follow official instructions directly from the [author's website](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

Comment: Possibly related to Steam: [Error when updating in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350839/error-when-updating-in-terminal)